# compass apks subtracting West declination to return True bearing when it should be added to obtain True

Tags: compass-geolocation

Could a member take time to point out my error in understanding:

**Problem:** compass in lat/long with west declination of 8 deg (-8deg) magnetic e.g. lat/long has 8 deg west declination Magnetic:

**My understanding:** to correct to True heading - True north the 8 deg should be added to the magnetic.
**
Issue:** I have looked at several compass apks, and all have subtracted the declination. Only East declination is subtracted. West declination is always added.

pretty sure that is wrong. Please advise Thank you!!! mark

To convert Mag. to True heading when declination present:

West (-) declination is added

East (+) declination is subtracted